# Javascript setInterval clearing itself?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there's a way to make `setInterval` clear itself.

Something like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    alert(1);
    clearInterval(this);
}, 2000);
```

I want it to keep checking thing if it's finished it will stop.

Comment: In this example at least, it would make more sense just to use `setTimeout`.

Comment: perhaps you would prefer `setTimeout` instead

Comment: agh GGG beat me to it :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    alert(1);
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}, 2000);
```

Alternative way is using `setTimeout()` if you know it is just one time call.

Comment: nah its not like this
i want it to keep checking thing if its finished its will stop :)

Comment: Brilliant, but what if the interval was set from inside an object? `bar = { zaa : function(){ this.int = setinterval(function(){clearInterval(this.int)},100)}}; foo = new bar.zaa();`

Answer (score 9):

```
(​function() {
    var runs = 3;
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Number " + runs);                         
        --runs;
        if (runs == 0) {
             clearInterval(i);
        }    
    }, 1000);
}());​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzBKG/)