# Javascript setInterval function to clear itself?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

```
myInterval = setInterval(function(){
     MyFunction();
},50);

function MyFunction()
{
    //Can I call clearInterval(myInterval); in here?
}
```

The interval's not stopping (not being cleared), if what I've coded above is fine then it'll help me look elsewhere for what's causing the problem. Thanks.

EDIT: Let's assume it completes a few intervals before clearInterval is called which removes the need for setTimeout.

Comment: no you cann't if these functions are created in the different scope. And as @xtofl wrote it had be better use recursive calls of `setTimeout` function

Comment: Why would recursive calls of setTimeout be more appropriate? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `setInterval` has few problems, just read this article - http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript setInterval clearing itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747139/javascript-setinterval-clearing-itself)

Comment: **Use [setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24478037/9157799). [Recursive setTimeout isn't actually recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63503930/9157799)** and won't create nested call stack. Watch [this video](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ) if you haven't heard of JS event loop.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

As long as you have scope to the saved `interval` variable, you can cancel it from anywhere.

In an "child" scope:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
     clearInterval(myInterval);
},50);
```

In a "sibling" scope:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
     foo();
},50);

var foo = function () {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
};
```

You could even pass the interval if it would go out of scope:

```
var someScope = function () {
    var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        foo(myInterval);
    },50);
};

var foo = function (myInterval) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
};
```

Comment: How can `myInterval` be passed to `foo` when the `setInterval` hasn't been evaluated yet?

Comment: @Melab which of the three code block examples are you referring to?

Comment: Just to note, testing this using `let` instead of `var` doesn't seem to work in a react app

Comment: @Melab the function inside `setInterval` is not executing on creation but called by `setInterval`, meaning that `myInterval` would already be evaluated

Answer (score 11):

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

will do the trick to cancel the Interval whenever you need it.
If you want to immediately cancel after the first call, you should take `setTimeout` instead. And sure you can call it in the Interval function itself.

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (/* condition here */){
        clearInterval(myInterval);
   } 
}, 50);
```

see an [EXAMPLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/vDmHA/).

Comment: But can this be called within the interval itself? i.e. can it stop itself?

Comment: Yep, no probs, I removed my comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (condition) clearInterval(interval); // here interval is undefined, but when we call this function it will be defined in this context
}, 50);
```

Or

```
var callback = function() { if (condition) clearInterval(interval); }; // here interval is undefined, but when we call this function it will be defined in this context
var interval = setInterval(callback, 50);
```

Comment: I'm getting a few different answers here, and yours seems to be the ideal one as I'm needing to cancel it 'within' the interval itself. Going by the first part of your answer what I've done in the OP is ok, so I'm going to assume there's no problem there.

Answer (score 3):

From your code what seems you want to do is to run a function and run it again and again until some job is done...

That is actually a task for the `setTimeout()`, the approach is similar:

```
    var myFunction = function(){
      if( stopCondition ) doSomeStuff(); //(do some stuff and don't run it again)
        else setTimeout( myFunction, 50 );
    }
    myFunction(); //immediate first run
```

## Simple as that :)

Of course if you REALLY want to use setInterval for some reason, @jbabey's answer seems to be the best one :)

Comment: If you down vote, please comment on what was wrong/badly done,  thank you :)

Comment: I know SO is known for "How to do A?" "You don't do A, you do B" but seriously, this is actually [the preferred way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12092439/9157799#comment133408747_12092439).

Comment: @MImamPratama Although I agree with that for most cases, I wouldn't force that, sometimes you don't care about sequence, but just a regular trigger - in that time setInterval could (still doesn't have to) be a better option

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using a trick with window.setTimeout

```
var Interval = function () {
    if (condition) {
        //do Stuff
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(Interval, 20);
    };
};
window.setTimeout(Interval, 20);
```