# How a run count down again after 3 seconds in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous, web

The circular count down from 10 to 1 is working properly but I want to start the count down again (from 10 to 1 without reload) after a pause of 3 seconds. I have tried using a setTimeOut within a setTimeOut but it is not working. Here is the code.

```js
var countdownNumberEl = document.getElementById('countdown-number');
var countdown = 10;

countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;

setInterval(function() {
  countdown = --countdown <= 0 ? 10 : countdown;

  countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;
  
  setInterval(function(){
 countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;

  },3000)
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
  <div id="countdown-number"></div>
  <svg>
    <circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your code with `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 6):

just add 3 sec as initial and change textContent when it will be less then 10

```js
let countdownNumberEl = document.getElementById('countdown-number');
let countdown = 10;

countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;

setInterval(function() {
  countdown = --countdown <= 0 ? 13 : countdown;

  if (countdown > 10) {
     return;
  }
  countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
  <div id="countdown-number"></div>
  <svg>
    <circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with a pointer function.
I stop the interval at reaching 1, and use setTimeout() to start a new interval.

```js
startInterval = () => {
  // setup markup and count
  let countdownNumberEl = document.getElementById('countdown-number');
  let countdown = 10;
  countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;

  // start the interval
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    --countdown;
    if(countdown < 1) {
      // stop interval
      clearInterval(intervalId); 
      // pause and start a new interval
      setTimeout(startInterval, 3000);         
    } else {
      // update markup
      countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

startInterval();
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
  <div id="countdown-number"></div>
  <svg>
    <circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

ref: [Javascript setInterval function to clear itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092439/javascript-setinterval-function-to-clear-itself)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you have tried to solve the problem with nested setTimeout functions. It is also possible to do that:

```js
const countdownNumberEl = document.getElementById('countdown-number');

const repeatCountdownFrom = (n, waitTimeout) => {
  countdownFrom(n, () => 
    setTimeout(() => 
      repeatCountdownFrom(n, waitTimeout)
    , waitTimeout)
  )
}

const countdownFrom = (n, callbackWhenDone) => {
  if(n >= 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      countdownNumberEl.textContent = n;
      countdownFrom(n - 1, callbackWhenDone);
     }, 1000);
  } else {
    callbackWhenDone();
  }
}

repeatCountdownFrom(10, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown-number"></div>
```