# Can't clearInterval on my script, but why?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a simple turn game in JS, and i need to make those battle interactions to have some delay.

I am using setInverval to automatize everything after the player presses 'Battle!', but when checking if he's still alive for it, my clearInterval doesn't work - the process is still running in the background o_o

```
    const player = {
    hp: 0,
    state: true
}

const enemy = {
    hp: 100,
    state: true
}

function checkHp() {
    if(player.hp === 0 || enemy.hp === 0){
        const start = setInterval(function() {
            console.log('Checando turnos...'),
            battle()
        }, 2000)
        return start
    } else {
        clearInterval(start)
        console.log('Você precisa descansar!')
    }
}

function battle() {
    turn = 0
    turn = Math.floor(Math.random () * 2)
    console.log(turn)
}

checkHp()
```

Comment: `start` is out-of-scope. It's declared in one branch of the `if` statement but you're using it anothe branch.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `start` is out-of-scope when you are trying to use it to clear your interval. Let's break down what your code is doing:

```js
function checkHp() {
    if(player.hp === 0 || enemy.hp === 0){
        // start is defined here in the scope of this block
        const start = setInterval(function() {
            console.log('Checando turnos...'),
            battle()
        }, 2000)
        // it is returned from the function here
        return start
    } else {
        // start has never been defined inside the else block, so it
        // has a value of undefined
        clearInterval(start)
        console.log('Você precisa descansar!')
    }
}
```

It might be helpful to read up about [variable scoping in javascript](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/variables-in-javascript).

Later in the script you call `checkHp`, but you don't save the return value, which is the interval handle if it entered the `if` block or `undefined` if you entered the else block, from which you don't return a value.

Now, what to do about this? It seems like you're probably trying to set up an interval that clears itself under certain conditions. You might check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9747139/12162258) for some advice on that.

Comment: Thanks! I thinked that if/else had a sharing scope, i'll try to figure out how to workaround it - it's more clear why im a failling todo some simple things using js :P

Answer (score 0):

`clearInterval` can't work for `undefined` arguments. Put `start` variable out of `if` condition for `clearInterval` to work. From

```js
function checkHp() {
    if(player.hp === 0 || enemy.hp === 0){
        const start = setInterval(function() {
            console.log('Checando turnos...'),
            battle()
        }, 2000)
        return start
    } else {
        clearInterval(start)
        console.log('Você precisa descansar!')
    }
}
```

to

```
function checkHp() {
// this line new added
const start;
    if(player.hp === 0 || enemy.hp === 0){
// this line will edited
        start = setInterval(function() {
            console.log('Checando turnos...'),
            battle()
        }, 2000)
        return start
    } else {
        clearInterval(start)
        console.log('Você precisa descansar!')
    }
}
```

`clearInterval` always works as `setInterval` is assigned with variables. So `start` variable should be assigned out of `if` condition first.

Javascript variables can have global scope and can also have local scope. Local scope can not touchable in global scope but global scope variable can be used in local scale. These scopes can be decided by `function`, `if` and other methods which have curly brackets(`{}`). We can see one example,

```js
let a = 'apple'

function printA() {

//will console apple in this local function
console.log(a)

return
}

printA();
```

Above example `apple` can be consoled in the function,

```js
let a;

function asignA() {

a = 'banana'

return
}

printA();

//this will console apple still in global scale
//will not console banana 
//because asigning banana was declared in local scope
console.log(a)
```

in this example, assigned `banana` can not be consoled out of the function.